# Box Job status after onhol

Tags: autosys

If a box job contains 10 jobs & out of 9 nos of jobs are completed successfully but one Job is in On-Hold status. what will be the status of the BOX Job ?

Answer (score 0):

if the box job is defined with the condition of s(child_on_hold_job) then it will show running only.